# Escaping nested double quotes during objectMapper.readValue()

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to read an object into my model using objectMapper

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
result = objectMapper.readValue(process.getData(), params.class);
```

under one of the keys of params there is a string

```
href=\"${organizationParams.get(\"info.facebook\")}\">
```

so after readValue happens the string looks like

```
href="${organizationParams.get("info.facebook")}">
```

and then later on I have call to `Jsoup.clean()` which truncates the string to

```
href="${organizationParams.get("
```

This is not desirable. Any ideas on how to retain the string after Jsoup.clean?

Comment: Your JSON contains HTML? How do you pass it to Jsoup? How is Jsoup involved?

Comment: My json contains many html documents. So I need to clean the documents before storing in database. I have my own whitelist defined for jsoup.clean() which works for everything else but nested double quotes

Comment: This seems like a Jsoup issue then. Figure out how to retain (if that's what you want) javascript appearing in HTML tag attributes. Jackson is not involved.

Comment: well I think thats exactly what my question is :)